# Powerapps range of dates between 2 dates

Tags: datetime, if-statement, powerapps-canvas

I am creating a calendar in power apps and trying to highlight a task between 2 dates I can select 1 date with code A but unable to select multiple days between dates Code B, has anyone managed this? the error i get is:-

Invalid argument type expecting one of the following, Number, decimal, date, time, datetime, untyped object

Code A - Working for single date

```
If(
!IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Name_Ref_Label.Text && 
Task_Type_Short=Task_Label_Short.Text && 
        Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") = 
Text(DateTimeValue(Date_Ref_Label.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    )
),
LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,Task_Type_Short = Task_Label_Short.Text,Task_Type_Long),

Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=2 || Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=3 || 
Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=4 || Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=5  || 
Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=6,"Faulting",
""
)
```

Code B - I would like to select multiple dates within a range

```
  If(
 !IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Name_Ref_Label.Text && 
 Task_Type_Short=Task_Label_Short.Text && 
        Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_From), "yyyy-mm-dd") >= 
 Text(DateTimeValue(Date_Ref_Label.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd") &&
        Text(DateValue(Date_of_Task_To), "yyyy-mm-dd") <= 
 Text(DateTimeValue(Date_Ref_Label.Text), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    )
 ),
 LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,Task_Type_Short = Task_Label_Short.Text,Task_Type_Long),

 Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=2 || Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=3 || 
 Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=4 || Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=5  || 
 Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=6,"Faulting",
 ""
 )
```

Ok, This code gives no errors but only shows the item with date in 'Date_of_Task_From'

```
If(
!IsBlank(
    LookUp(
        RP_Tasks_SPList, Task_Owner = Name_Ref_Label.Text && 
Task_Type_Short=Task_Label_Short.Text && 
        Date_of_Task_From <= DateTimeValue(Date_Ref_Label.Text) &&
        Date_of_Task_To >= DateTimeValue(Date_Ref_Label.Text)
    )
),
LookUp(RP_Tasks_SPList,Task_Type_Short = 
Task_Label_Short.Text,Task_Type_Long),

Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=2 || Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=3 || 
Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=4 || Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=5  || 
Weekday(Date_Ref_Label.Text)=6,"Faulting",
""
)
```

Comment: Ok, This code gives no errors but only shows the item with date in 'Date_of_Task_From'